# Prevent PWA install prompt chrome 76 on desktop?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Chrome 76 has introduced a button in the omnibox to "Install App" if the PWA criteria is met.

Is there a way to prevent this button from appearing in the omnibox for chrome desktop?

Comment: Why create a PWA if you do not want it installed? - Just wondering

Comment: Right now I only want to offer installation on mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you want to prevent the default so as to show a customized install banner, [read here](https://love2dev.com/blog/beforeinstallprompt/).

However, this script would totally prevent the install banner!

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This only prevents the display of the install banner prompt. On chrome desktop, the address bar (omnibox) has a button now (a circle with a plus sign). I wish to hide this.

Comment: Then you prevent the service worker from installing, on non-mobile device, That's the only way I have been able to find. Updated my answer!

Answer (score 3):

For making your PWA installable **only on mobile** and **not on desktop** you can choose one of the following methods:

1. **Redirect** to a subdomain or another domain that **does not have a manifest file**
2. If you are using Server-Side-Rendering, **remove the manifest `link` tag** before sending to the client

   ```html
   <!-- do not include this if the client userAgent is a desktop device (wide screen) -->
   <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
   ```
3. **Remove manifest on the client** once the page is loaded on desktop

   ```js
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mobile') === -1) {
       document.querySelector('link[rel="manifest"]').remove();
     }
   });
   ```

That way it will make your PWA not installable and thus not showing the Add to Home screen in the omnibox.