# How do I remove the PWA install button from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, progressive-web-apps, userscripts

On my desktop PC, I do not wish to see the PWA install button in my Google Chrome address bar, nor see the option to install in the menu. I have no intention of installing or using them and I don't want to have them constantly pushed into my face.

On my Android phone I want the same, but I also want to see a warning if I am about to install a PWA from the Play Store by accident because it wasn't properly revealed to be a PWA.

Is there a hidden setting or flag in my browser that I can turn off? Can I use Tampermonkey? HELP!

(I don't want to go into detail why I want this except to say that one company is trying to force a PWA on me without offering me the option to get my money back because I'm no longer receiving the software or service I paid for. I also have yet to see a PWA that offers something its website doesn't.)

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site about programming related questions. Please post your question on the appropriate site for how to use your web browser. (possibly superuser, please check guidelines before posting)

Comment: Would the question fit here better if I asked if there is a way to program the requested behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent PWA install prompt chrome 76 on desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57556321/prevent-pwa-install-prompt-chrome-76-on-desktop)